# Objects Not Really Deleted?

Tags: physics, outliner

When an object is deleted from the scene, is it still present somewhere in the Blender file? For example, I've been playing with physics constraints, so I created and deleted a bunch of cubes. So now even though there are only 2 cubes and one constraint in the 3D Viewport and the Outliner, there are dozens in the object drop-down (only a few fit in the window).

[image: only 2 cubes]

[image]

[image]

That wouldn't be a problem by itself, but I noticed that the Rigid Bodies behave strangely after creating and deleting objects and constraints. It seems that those "phantom" objects are interfering with the physics engine.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I've copped this several times so now after removing physics in particular, I check the Dopesheet and look for physics related strips for that object.  The same applies when deleting a physic'd object.  I also make a save after deletion, exit Blender.  You could also check the current project's and temporary folders. Remove everything in the latter and check for caching folders in the former.

Comment: @Edgel3D  >> _You could also check the current project's and temporary folders._

<br>Sorry, I don't see any relevant files in the project folder, or in the File Paths|Data|Temporary Files folder. Could you please tell me where else to look? Thanks!

Comment: No unfortunately.  It's as though there's a cache or some flag in ram that you can't reset even when you exit Blender, it's still there when you reload! With these it's often a matter of reverting to a previous save and once you get it working again, bake the action to keyframes and remove the physics and/or constraint altogether. Once baked, the action is rock solid so long as nothing else is acting on the object. The worst offender for myself has definitely been physics.

Comment: Continuing - You can delete an object's physics and physic related strips still remain in the Dopesheet.  Delete these and often quirky behavior returns to normal.

You mention when you look in the 'Object drop down', there a dozens more. Are you talking about the Outliner entries or somewhere else?  If it's the Outliner, try purging orphaned data in the Outliner's menu, select 'Orphaned Data' (think that's what it's called). That will list several items as a rule.  Scroll the Outliner's header strip to the right until you see 'Purge'.  Keep selecting this until all that's left is 'Brushes'

Comment: 1) _Are you talking about the Outliner entries or somewhere else?_ I was referring to the lists that appear for example in Rigid Body Constraint | Objects | First and in other similar UI elements. 2) Thank you for the idea with "Orphaned Data". It worked. I also had to toggle an icon that looks like an "ON/OFF" switch. After that and a couple more clicks, the 39 useless objects has been deleted! Could you enter your advice as an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete an object's physics and physic related strips still remain in the Dopesheet.
Delete these and often quirky behavior returns to normal.

Try purging orphaned data in the Outliner's menu. 
Select 'Orphaned Data' (think that's what it's called). That will list several items as a rule. Scroll the Outliner's header strip to the right until you see 'Purge'. Keep selecting this until all that's left is 'Brushes'

Comment: Thank you for the idea with "Orphaned Data". It worked. I also had to toggle an icon that looks like an "ON/OFF" switch. After that and a couple more clicks, the 39 useless objects has been deleted!